# Как найти кол-во чисел в заданном диапазоне, у которых все цифры разные?

Tags: python, комбинаторика

найти кол-во чисел в заданном диапазоне, у которых все цифры разные(не считая границу)
Например:
диапазон(20:33) ==> все числа кроме 22 и  того получим 11 чисел
Числа до 1000 получается посчитать, но если число больше, то возникают проблемы.
диапазон(5000:50000) ==> ???

Код для 1000:

```
    # диапазон от 0 до 1000
if finish >= 1000 and finish < 10000:
    while finish > start:
        d = finish
        if  d % 10 != d//100 and d %10 != d//10 % 10 and d//10 % 10 != d//100 and d%10 != 0 :
            s3 += 1
            print(d)
        finish = finish - 1
    s3 = s3 + 90
```

Comment: Так и где ваш код? Только правильно говорить "числа, у которых все **цифры** разные", а то "числа, у которых числа" - это непонятно что.

Comment: Подозреваю что вы используете цикл. Эта задача имеет аналитическое решение

Comment: @MaxU Да так то пока речь не о миллиардах, думаю, и циклы справятся, это всё-равно копейки )

Comment: @CrazyElf, автор утверждает, что до 1000 программа работает правильно ;)

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, не заметил ошибку в названии

Comment: @kek4ok В тексте вопроса есть та же ошибка, которая была в названии ;)  А по сути вы как-то очень хитро считаете. Не понимаю, как у вас, например, 212 по этой логике нормально обрабатывается, ведь вы только две подряд одинаковые цифры таким образом проверяете, а через одну уже не должно получиться.

Comment: @CrazyElf не тот код прикрепил, это был для чисел до 100

Comment: @kek4ok В общем, читайте ответ Zhihar, там правильный метод. А так вручную проверять цифры вы замучаетесь.

Comment: для получения диапазона чисел используйте range (start, stop, step), а не ту громоздкую конструкцию, что у вас в коде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

чтобы понять, что все цифры у числа разные можно получить множество цифр (по сути это уникальные цифры) и сравнить с кол-вом цифр

например так:

```
len(set(map(int, str(value)))) == len(str(value))
```

Comment: map не нужен. Повторяющиеся цифры и так отбросятся

Comment: @EzikBro, точно, не подумал :)